# postgresql: how to get three rows with three different conditions at once from same table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `table1`. with columns `sn`, `rt` and `type`

I want to get rows with different `rt` (i.e rt = 1,2,3) column conditions

```
(SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE sn = 'testing' AND rt = 1 AND type = 'pump'
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1)

UNION


(SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE sn = 'testing' AND rt = 2 AND type = 'pump'
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1)


UNION

(SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE sn = 'testing' AND rt = 3 AND type = 'pump'
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1)
```

Currently i am trying the above.

Which is the effective way to get the rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rt ORDER BY id DESC) rn
  FROM table1
  WHERE sn = 'testing' AND type = 'pump' AND rt IN (1, 2, 3) 
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

You can omit `AND rt IN (1, 2, 3)` if 1, 2 and 3 are the only possible values for `rt`.

Comment: does `rn`  means row number (i,e like LIMIT=1)

Comment: @Santhosh yes rn is a row number and WHERE t.rn = 1 returns only the 1st of each partition.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do `JOIN`s between the table and itself, then specify the conditions in the singular `WHERE` clause. I've done a rough sketch of it below:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.*
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table1 AS t2
ON t1.sn = t2.sn AND t1.type = t2.type -- If you've got more reasonable connections between your datapoints, use them here
JOIN table1 AS t3
ON t.sn = t3.sn AND t1.type = t3.type
WHERE t1.rt = 1 AND t2.rt = 2 AND t3.rt = 3
ORDER BY t1.id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Depending on what other requirements you have, you may have to tweak some parts of that. If you want results when t1 has a value but t2 or t3 doesn't you can use a `LEFT JOIN` instead.